# structuremap objectfactory life time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, ioc-container

i've been using structuremap since a couple of months. I always use ObjectFactory.GetInstance to take the right instance of the object i've to use.

Actually, i need to understand which is the default ObjectFactory's InstanceScope. Is it ThreadLocal?

do u know where i can read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first result on google for "structuremap lifecycle":

http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/Scoping.htm

"PerRequest" is the default lifecycle if you didnt specify one in your registry

Comment: The Url is not valid any more, new Url: [`StructureMap - Scoping and Lifecycle Management`](http://docs.structuremap.net/Scoping.htm)